# I'm having trouble making buttons

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I have to do a button design how to do but I could not do. Could you help?
When the borders are hover it needs to arrive as effect. a button like the picture link below is required. I didn't get the image in the picture.

**I want to do:**
(https://pasteboard.co/I8gudAg.png)

**I made:**

```css
.btnc-secondary {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #f93140;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    outline-offset: -6px;
    outline: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.btnc-secondary:hover:after,
.btnc-secondary.active:after {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(98deg, #f93140, #f50a68);
}

.btnc-secondary[disabled] {
    background: #ededed;
    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0 !important;
    outline-color: #3f3f3f;
    color: #3d3d3d;
  
}

.btnc-secondary:active:after,
.btnc-secondary:active:before,
.btnc-secondary:after,
.btnc-secondary:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ff8a93;
    border-top: 1px solid #ff8a93;
    margin: 4px;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.btnc-secondary:hover,
.btnc-secondary.active {
    background: #ffffff;
    outline-color: #f50a68;
    color: #f93140;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.btnc-secondary.active {
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(6deg, #c20101, #bc070e) !important;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(6deg, #c20101, #bc070e) !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(84deg, #c20101, #bc070e) !important;
}

.btnc-secondary:active {
    background: #ff0013;
    outline-color: #ffffff !important;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>


<a class="btn btnc-secondary btn-sm fs-14 font-opensans" href="#">Title</a>
```

Comment: You are using the `svg` tag and the `svg-animate` tag but there is no svg in your code. Where would you like to use svg animations?

Comment: I want to make buttons with Svg. For example: (https://codepen.io/Gingernaut/pen/qOgMLy)

Answer (score 1):

The example you are giving in the comment is flawed since it's using a div inside an SVG element.

Next comes my example. It's an svg element that will take the width of it's parent element. If you prefer you can give the svg a fixed width.

The animation takes 3s, but you can change it to what you want by changing the value for `--t`

I'm using `hsl` colors and I'm changing the lightness to change the color.

I hope this is what you were asking.

```css
body{--t:3s}/*time*/

rect{stroke:hsl(254,57%,55%);}


svg{background:hsl(254,57%,95%);
  transition:all var(--t) ease;
  font-family:Arial;
  
}
text{text-anchor:middle;
  pointer-events:none;
  fill:hsl(254,57%,45%);
  transition:all var(--t) ease-in-out; 
}


.shape{
  fill:none;
  stroke:hsl(254,57%,45%);
  stroke-dasharray:95px;
  stroke-dashoffset:95px;
  transition:all var(--t) ease;  
}

/*HOVER*/

svg:hover{background:hsl(254,57%,55%)}

svg:hover .shape{
  stroke:hsl(254,57%,75%);
  stroke-dasharray:380px;
  stroke-dashoffset:0px;
}

svg:hover text{fill:hsl(254,57%,95%)}
```

```html
 <a href="">
 <svg viewBox="-5 -5 160 50" >
   <rect  height="40" width="150" fill="none" stroke-width=".5"  />
   <path class="shape" d="M60,0L150,0 150,40 0,40 0,0 60,0"  />
   <text x="75" y="25" >Button 1</text>
</svg></a>
```